# Sci-fi book in which a scientist transfers his soul into a spaceship in order to restart humanity

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read this book a bit of a while ago. It's basically about a scientist who was warning everyone that Earth was gonna go kaboom, but when no one took him seriously, he found a material that lets them transfer one's soul into it, so he makes a spaceship and transfers his soul to it, containing basically everything needed to restart humanity.

Comment: When was "a bit of a while ago"? Was it a paperback? A hardback? An eBook? Was it in English? Do you remember if the material was a metal, a plastic, some sort of ceramic or glass? How long was the book? A 30 page chap book? A 100 page novelette? A 250 page paperback? A real doorstopper? And does the book end with him leaving Earth, or does it explore his voyage?

Comment: Was it ever serialised on TV or made into film - it rings bells for me.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots the book was online, the material was metal, cant remember how many chapters, this was years ago, and i described how it started, i never finished it sadly

Comment: @immaturedemolitions: Did it look like it was posted as a complete book, or as serial chapters on the website?

Comment: Some small similarity to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/sci-fi-story-where-a-pilot-transfers-his-consciousness-into-his-ship-and-explore?rq=1, but no enemy alien race here.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it was more of a serial chapter style i believe

Comment: Another nonmatching story of brain uploading at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190205/space-book-where-earth-has-been-abandoned-due-to-pollution/190225#190225